# Perelman's lectures

Tags: online-resources, ricci-flow

I can't find any videos of lectures that Grigori Perelman gave for his proof of Poincare's conjecture. For example, the following is a picture of one of his lecture in US.

[image]

Edit. I was studying his papers so I thought maybe I can learn much more through his lectures. A lot of lectures have been asked in MSE, I hope I won't get closing vote. I aim to learn by this very question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not everything's recorded...

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122,  I'm sure it must have been recorded but may not available for free online

Comment: Have you been able to find any lectures of his?  I've looked on youtube and have not had any luck finding any.

Comment: There are [lecture notes](http://comet.lehman.cuny.edu/sormani/others/perelman/perelman.html) available.

Comment: @TyeCampbell, not a single one, so I asked here maybe some links in university websites available?

Comment: If I had been hosting such lectures, I certainly would have wanted to have them recorded for posterity.  But of course I was not, and also it would require Perelman's consent to be recorded.

Comment: "it would require Perelman's consent to be recorded", it seems unlikely he would've granted it.